# Weird issue with Month in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat

I tried to format my date time:

```
Locale locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
dateFormatDayMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d", locale);
textView.setText(dateFormatDayMonth.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

However, the result is `Sat, M10 2`. I expected it to be `Sat, Oct 2`. It's used to work before, but suddenly it's stopped working.
Is there anything I missed here?

Comment: the locale is `default`.

Comment: I know its default . i mean what value you r getting for locale ?

Comment: I logged it as `locale.toString()` and it's named `default`.  The text after formatting was `Sat, M10 2`. However, I am using English in my device, it should be `Sat, Oct 2`.

Comment: `LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM d"))`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A dummy Locale for the demo
        Locale localeFromResponse = new Locale("default");

        Locale locale = localeFromResponse.toString().equals("default") ? Locale.getDefault() : localeFromResponse;
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM d", locale);
        String formatted = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(dtf);
        System.out.println(formatted);

        // textView.setText(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tue, Oct 5
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/B5zqwN)

#### If you have an existing `java.util.Calendar` object

You can convert the existing `java.util.Calendar` object to `java.time.Instant` using [`Calendar#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toInstant--) which can in turn be converted into other Date-Time types of `java.time` API.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Dummy Locale and Calendar objects - for the demo
        Locale localeFromResponse = new Locale("default");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Locale locale = localeFromResponse.toString().equals("default") ? Locale.getDefault() : localeFromResponse;
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM d", locale);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = calendar.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        String formatted = zdt.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(formatted);

        // textView.setText(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tue, Oct 5
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/0Dz3wx)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

#### Just in case you need to do it using the legacy API

For any reason, if you want to stick to the legacy API, you can map the `Locale` in the same way as I have done above i.e. it will be

```
Locale localeFromResponse = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

Locale locale = localeFromResponse.toString().equals("default") ? Locale.getDefault() : localeFromResponse;
dateFormatDayMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d", locale);
textView.setText(dateFormatDayMonth.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your date format just like this

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d", locale);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    outputDate.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```